# Heap Allocation in ZGC

Tags: performance, garbage-collection, heap-memory, zgc, java-heap

My application uses 20 GB of RAM for storing the session data i.e. JVM size to store. The sessions are referred, updated and cleared continuously producing qt high number of unused objects every second (around 2 Gb in 5 to 10 minutes). We are planning to move from G1 to ZGC considering its low latency benefits. The main doubt considering the testing of ZGC is how much head room should I give for the ZGCs internal requirements considering its view on Java heap marked0, marked1, remapped which has 3 different virtual memory mappings.

The is just the head room I have to provide for ZGC internal requirements like 20% more, other buffers related to application, we will provide based on the memory occupation. I could not find a proper recommendation for this.

Thanks
Nav

ZGC Tuning, the -Xms & -Xmx configurations were referred from current G1 configs as it is now but would like to understand if we need to have a higher Xm allocation considering ZGC memory requirements.

Comment: “2 Gb in 5 to 10 minutes” is not a high number. And the wrong number to look at anyway. You say you want to change the GC for “low latency benefits”, so what is your current latency and how much gain do you expect from the change?

Comment: The idea was to give an overview of the system memory use up. During full dimensioned load, we see latency variations between 120 to 700ms and at times above 1 second which is contributed by GC for 12 GB. But the average if you consider is always ok. So to understand ZGC, I decided to try it out and was mainly looking for the buffer i need to consider above the application requirements.

Comment: If you want to “try it out”, just go ahead. No stranger on the internet can give you a better answer than the results of actual tests with your specific application. In fact, I would distrust every answer of the “xyz % is always the best option” kind.